# Classic ASP IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: email, iis, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I am creating contact us form on windows 7 IIS 7.5.

I have classic ASP page and when I try to post my form with ASP page for sending email.. It gives me below error:
IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Any settings I need to do in IIS to handle classic ASP??? As it works fine on windows xp.

If I do with GET in place of POST.. it gives IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 404.3 - Not Found error.

Comment: Check if ASP is enabled in the IIS setup. Look in Control Panel/Add or remove.../install windows features and then find and expand the nodes "Internet Information Services/WWW/Functions for programdevelopment" and check the ASP-node (the naming of above nodes are somewhat inaccurate, as my Windows 7 is in danish - sorry for that :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have IIS6 installed on your XP.

You should check this: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8